# RSS in a Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rss

is there any way to show an image for RSS feess in my wordpress page...
it os because currently defaul wordpress RSS feeds will only show a text of other feeds from other site..how can i make my site show a thumb image of rss feeds of th other sites..below are example of the rss feeds on my site. plizzz help me.i really needs a help from all of u guys....

[image]

Comment: Which version of Wordpress are you using?

Comment: i'm using wordpress 3.0

Comment: Questions like this should be sent to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can "hook" into the RSS feed and call 1 attachment (thumbmail)

Add this line to your functions.php file...

This example will add 3 thumbs, but simply change the "numberposts" to your desired amount...

```
/* Adding 3 thumbs to the top of the post on RSS */
    function rss_custom_format($content) {
    //prob uneccessary but checking that it is in fact a feed
    if(is_feed()){

       global $post;
       if(!$post->ID){return;}

       $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => 3,
            'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        ); 


       $attachments = get_posts($args);

       if($attachments){
       $thumb = '';    
       foreach($attachments as $attachment){
        $thumb .= wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID,'thumbnail','true').'&nbsp;';
       }

     } 
    }
    $thumb .= '<div style="clear:both; width:100%;"></div>';
    $content = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$content);
    $more = '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">Read More ...</a>';
    return $thumb.$content.$more;

    }

    add_filter('the_content_rss','rss_custom_format');
    add_filter('the_excerpt_rss','rss_custom_format');
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\xampplite\htdocs\xampp\blog\wp-content\themes\structure\functions.php on line 83                                         --> this is error happen when i put in on my theme functions.php

Comment: That usually means you're missing a closing ';' or a '}' somewhere in your code. Add one more '}' to the very end.

Comment: already put it and the same problem happen

Comment: can you paste in line 83? That's the most likey the culprit. I have used this code on several sites so I know it's good. I think you need one last '}'

Comment: /* Adding 3 thumbs to the top of the post on RSS */
function rss_custom_format($content) {
//prob uneccessary but checking that it is in fact a feed
if(is_feed()){

global $post;
if(!$post->ID){return;}

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => 3,
'orderby' => 'menu_order ID',
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'order' => 'ASC'
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);

if($attachments){
$thumb = '';
foreach($attachments as $attachment){
$thumb .= wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID,'thumbnail','true').' ';
}

?>

Comment: Apologies! The code I pasted in was cut off. I have updated the code. Looks like a quite a few important bits were cut off.

Comment: It still has a problem..it does't show anything

Comment: Try adding an arbitrary string to the feed url, you may be viewing the cached version. Example yoursite.com/feed?randomtext Also, I pasted the code I use in "code" format that I use, which additionally filters out the [...] and adds in a "read more..." in it's place.

Answer (score 0):

Your feed is hacked. This is not programming related, go ask on server fault.
See http://wordpress.org/support/topic/blog-was-hacked-rss-issue-but-now-i-get-garbled-text-what-does-this-mean